# How to convert a high resolution image into a lower one?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image

In my page, I have a module in which I upload images and then I display them in 2 places.

Recently I got a work to show only the low-resolution image in one place and the same uploaded image in another place. For that, I have to store 2 images, one for high resolution (The actual image uploaded) and another with low resolution (Converted image). I am using Node.js.

Can anyone please suggest me help to convert the image into low resolution?

Comment: Show what you've tried and how you think it isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to resize the images on the backend, you can use:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemagick

From the docs:

```
var im = require('imagemagick');
im.resize({
  srcPath: 'kittens.jpg',
  dstPath: 'kittens-small.jpg',
  width:   256
}, function(err, stdout, stderr){
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('resized kittens.jpg to fit within 256x256px');
});
```

If you want to resize on the frontend, you can use Canvas, see:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick is quite hard to work with and complicated installation.

I definitely suggest to use: https://github.com/lovell/sharp as it is 'plug and play' solution and it is really nice documented.